# Checkboxes count selected checkboxes, sometimes returns an error

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, checkbox, count

I am using an accordion, divided into 5 categories, showing several rows of checkboxes. When the visitor selects a checkbox, it returns the amount of selected checkboxes per category. Nothing is shown when none of the checkboxes are selected. E.g.

```
Category 1: 2 checkboxes selected
Category 2: 1 checkboxes selected
Category 3:
Category 4: 10 checkboxes selected
Category 5:
```

This works, so when the visitor adds another one in category 4 it will show "11 checkboxes selected". Also when one is turned off, it of course shows "9 checkboxes selected".

However, this works 95% of the time. When I randomly click the checkboxes, it sometimes returns an error in the log

```
Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function studiezoeker:487Request studiezoeker:487(anonymous function) studiezoeker:479v.event.dispatch ScriptResource.axd?d=dNZi6RW_20g0sp3isLHt5GoHGXYiqvO1u3-FU9wcgPXyQCu1rmFi0RuSIwIzaJjczNe7S8D3OTnoIX…:2o.handle.u
```

The counter in this case will be stuck at whatever it was. In this example, category 4 will be stuck at 10. However, when I now click another one, the results are correct again. 12 selected will be shown.

I've searched for hours, but I just can't find it.

**The Javascript-part where it goes wrong. It goes wrong within the first 4 lines.**

```
 $(".filtercontainer .accordionitem").each(function () {
                    $(".beefup-body [type='checkbox']", this).change(function () {
                        var count = $(this).parent().parent().parent().delay(100).find($("[type='checkbox']:checked")).length;

                        console.log(count);

                        $(this).parent().parent().parent().siblings("h2").find(".checkCount").text(count + " geselecteerd");
                        if (count == 0) {
                            $(this).parent().parent().parent().siblings("h2").find(".checkCount").hide();
                        }
                        else {
                            $(this).parent().parent().parent().siblings("h2").find(".checkCount").show();
                        }
                    });
```

**The HTML (stripped down all checkboxes and all categories, so it's easier to read**

```
<div class="filtercontainer">
  <div class="Accordion">
    <div class="AccordionInner">
      <article class="taxonomy accordionitem open" data-taxonomy="school" role="article">
        <h2 class="beefup-head">school <span class="checkCount">14 selected</span></h2>
        <div class="beefup-body" style="display: block;">
          <div class="columncount">
            <div class="taxa" title="ade08e3b-77bc-6478-97b6-ff00006ae40d" data-taxa-id="ade08e3b-77bc-6478-97b6-ff00006ae40d">
              <input id="ade08e3b-77bc-6478-97b6-ff00006ae40d" type="checkbox" name="ctl00$Content$C022$cbFilter">
              <label class="coverCheckBox" for="ade08e3b-77bc-6478-97b6-ff00006ae40d"><span></span></label>
              <span class="filterName">One checkbox as an example</span>
              <!-- More checkboxes below this one, upto 40 per category -->
            </div>
            <div class="taxa" title="afe08e3b-77bc-6478-97b6-ff00006ae40d" data-taxa-id="afe08e3b-77bc-6478-97b6-ff00006ae40d"></div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </article>
      <article class="taxonomy accordionitem" data-taxonomy="vorm" role="article">
        <h2 class="beefup-head">vorm <span class="checkCount"></span></h2>
        <div class="beefup-body" style="display: none;">
          <div class="columncount">
            <!-- Checkboxes in this category as well -->
          </div>
        </div>
      </article>
      <!-- More categories containing their own checkboxes here as well -->
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It is the `delay()` which adds a race condition.

Comment: `each` is redundant when binding event

Comment: @DOCASAREL I tried the delay() in desperation after two hours of trial and error. Removing it doesn't do anything.

Comment: selectors in `find` don't need to be wrapped in `$()`

Comment: @Satpal Should I replace the each with something else?

Comment: @charlietfl I changed it to find("[type='checkbox']:checked"), but without succes.

Comment: suggest you create a demo that replicates the problem.

Comment: Sorry guys, I (as a jQuery newbie) was completely sure the error was in the above code. However, above is part of a search function. The error appears somewhere else in the doc where i use. if (request != null) {
            request.cancel(); I don't know why, but it seems to work now.